# Event being triggered for all instances

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am trying to implement the capability for a character to move to and pick up an item when the player double-clicks on it.

I've created an item scene with the following function:

```
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT and event.double_click:
            print(self.type, " (", self.position.x, ", ", self.position.y, ")")
            move_to_pickup.emit(self)
```

type is an integer unique to each instance.

In my main scene, I've created 3 instances.  When I double-click on one of those instances, I get the following output:

```
2 (416, 248)
1 (560, 496)
0 (880, 752)
```

My signal receiver also receives 3 signals, one from each instance.

Why am I seeing output from 3 instances when I'm only double-clicking on one? And how can I limit things so that my signal is sent out only from the instance I have chosen?

Answer (score 0):

The `_input` method receives input. Including pointing input regardless of where  it is. *As long as it wasn't taken by something else, but since you are getting the call, that isn't an issue here.*

Thus, to use `_input`, you would have to come up with your own solution to check if the input is on your instance.

I don't know the type of your instance…

- If it is a `CollisionObject3D` (`Area3D`, `CharacterBody3D`, `PhysicalBone3D`, `RigidBody3D`, `StaticBody3D`), check it has `input_ray_pickable` set to `true`, and use `_input_event(camera:Camera3D, event:InputEvent, position:Vector3, normal:Vector3, shape_idx:int) -> void`.
- Similarly, if it is a `CollisionObject2D` (`Area2D`, `CharacterBody2D`, `RigidBody2D`, `StaticBody2D`) check it has `input_ray_pickable` set to `true`, and use `_input_event (viewport:Viewport, event:InputEvent, shape_idx:int) -> void`.
- If it is a `Control` use `_gui_input (event:InputEvent) -> void`.

I suggest using whichever of the above is more appropriate (which might require changing your node type, or adding another node to handle the input).

Comment: So an input event, regardless of its origin, is sent to all nodes? That makes sense in retrospect. It means that Godot doesn't recognize an event as belonging to any particular node. But then it raises the question of how a node captures events meant specifically for them. Does that require another question to be asked?